# Go неверное выделение памяти для []byte или ошибка в go test benchmark?

Tags: golang, память, benchmark

Смотрим стандартный логгер из пакета log. В его структуре находится поле(свойство) buf:

```
type Logger struct {
  mu        sync.Mutex // ensures atomic writes; protects the following fields
  prefix    string     // prefix on each line to identify the logger (but see Lmsgprefix)
  flag      int        // properties
  out       io.Writer  // destination for output
  buf       []byte     // for accumulating text to write
  isDiscard int32      // atomic boolean: whether out == io.Discard
}
```

Функция log.New() также не инициализует это поле и оно остается nil, что видно под дебаггером. Если запустить вот такой бенчмарк с -benchmem:

```
var stdLgr = log.New(bufWriter, "", log.Ldate)
func Benchmark_Stdlog(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    bufWriter.Reset()
    stdLgr.Printf("any info message")
  }
}
```

То получаем:

```
Benchmark_Stdlog-4 360367 2898 ns/op 16 B/op 1 allocs/op
```

где наглядно видно что логгер делает только одну аллокацию и только для операции fmt.Sprintf() внутри себя. Хотя под дебагером видно, что слайс buf наращивает свою длину согласно принятому в Go алгоритму: 8, 16,32,64 байта.

Это ошибка бенчмарка, что он не видит аллокаций для полей структур типа []byte (возможно и иных слайсов!) или это особенное поведение компилятора Go для неинициализированного слайса байт?

Кстати, если заменить поле логгера на глобальный буфер этого же типа:
var buf []byte
то бенчмарк точно также не видит аллоцирование памяти функцией append()!

Кто-то может объяснить что происходит? Проверил на версии Go 1.20.0

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Вот прямое доказательство того, что `log` не делает переаллокации. Я скопировал `/usr/local/go/src/log/log.go` к себе и поменял видимость поля `buf` на `Buf`

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "reflect"
    "runtime"

    "example.org/trylog/mylog"
)
func main() {
    var ms0 runtime.MemStats
    l := mylog.New(os.Stdout, "", mylog.Ldate)
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms0)
    l.Println(ms0.Mallocs, ms0.Frees, cap(l.Buf), reflect.ValueOf(l.Buf).Pointer())
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms0)
    l.Println(ms0.Mallocs, ms0.Frees, cap(l.Buf), reflect.ValueOf(l.Buf).Pointer())
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms0)
    l.Println(ms0.Mallocs, ms0.Frees, cap(l.Buf), reflect.ValueOf(l.Buf).Pointer())
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms0)
    l.Println(ms0.Mallocs, ms0.Frees, cap(l.Buf), reflect.ValueOf(l.Buf).Pointer())
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms0)
    l.Println(ms0.Mallocs, ms0.Frees, cap(l.Buf), reflect.ValueOf(l.Buf).Pointer())

}
```

(пакет `example.org/trylog/mylog` - это мой пакет, в который я скопировал стандартный `log`)

Что получилось:

```
2023/04/02 134 2 0 0
2023/04/02 164 9 32 824633852064
2023/04/02 169 9 64 824633868416
2023/04/02 172 9 64 824633868416
2023/04/02 175 9 64 824633868416
```

Что видно - при первых двух вызовах `Buf` менялся - изменились размер и положение в памяти. А потом всё, размер зафиксировался, указатель перестал изменяться. Аллокации в последних вызовах происходят за счёт `fmt.Sprint` и `reflect.Valueof`.

**ИСХОДНЫЙ ОТВЕТ**

Я бы предположил, что аллокация, которую показывает бенчмарк, происходит только в `fmt.Sprintf`. Вот код `log.Printf`:

```
// Printf calls l.Output to print to the logger.
// Arguments are handled in the manner of fmt.Printf.
func (l *Logger) Printf(format string, v ...any) {
    if l.isDiscard.Load() {
        return
    }
    l.Output(2, fmt.Sprintf(format, v...))
}
```

Видно, что за сборку сообщения отвечает `fmt`. Функция `Output` пишет во внутренний буфер заголовок и готовую строку:

```
func (l *Logger) Output(calldepth int, s string) error {
    // ...
    l.buf = l.buf[:0]
    l.formatHeader(&l.buf, now, file, line)
    l.buf = append(l.buf, s...)
    if len(s) == 0 || s[len(s)-1] != '\n' {
        l.buf = append(l.buf, '\n')
    }
    _, err := l.out.Write(l.buf)
    return err
}
```

Как мне кажется, вот эта строчка делает весь фокус с нулевой аллокацией: `l.buf = l.buf[:0]`

Получается, что между вызовами функций логера внутренний буфер не изменяется в размерах (capacity), меняется только длина размещённых внутри данных. Другими словами, при нескольких первых прогонах бенчмарка этот буфер был аллоцирован до нужного размера, а затем памяти было достаточно, чтобы обойтись без аллокаций. Так как результаты бенчмарка содержат усреднённое значение, то несколько аллокаций, поделённые на тысячи прогонов, даёт среднее значение 0.

Проверка: давайте проверим число аллокаций для теста `stdLog.Print()`, то есть исключим из уравнения `fmt.Sprintf`. В этом случае в буфер пишется заголовок `время имя_файла:строка`, но не формируется строка сообщения.

```
func Benchmark_Stdlog_EmptyMsg(b *testing.B) {
    bz := make([]byte, 1024)
    bufWriter := bytes.NewBuffer(bz)
    var stdLgr = log.New(bufWriter, "", log.Ldate)
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        bufWriter.Reset()
        stdLgr.Print()
    }
}
```

```
Benchmark_Stdlog_EmptyMsg-8       653286          2531 ns/op           0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Видите? Ноль аллокаций.

Comment: Ваш вывод из примера не верен от слова совсем. Смотрите:

Comment: @Arhat109 куда смотреть?

Comment: Этого НЕ происходит только в двух случаях: если безразмерный слайс является полем структуры или он является глобалом. Вопрос был про это: как так, append() перевыделяет память (меняется cap), но аллокаций нет?

Comment: блин, где первая часть куда смотреть? .. ща.

Comment: Ваш пример интерпретирован Вами не верно: Вы просто не указали сообщение и fmt.Sprintf() не сделал аллокацию. Его можно тестировать отдельно, там все ровно. Ваш пример выдает в лог дату, но аллокаций нет, хотя под дебагом append() точно также добавляет cap в буфер лога пока делает сообщение. Как append() наращивает cap без аллокаций?

Comment: @Arhat109 `append` наращивает без аллокаций тогда, когда `capacity` достаточно для добавления новых данных. Я добавил прямой эксперимент с доступом к полю `buf` - видно, что массив перестаёт переаллоцироваться, пока достаточно места для новых записей. Логер не отдаёт память между вызовами.

Comment: Спасибо, достаточно наглядно. Тоже пришел к этому результату. Теперь у меня второй вопрос: откуда взялись 3 "лишние" аллокации? ;)

Comment: 2 аллокации приходятся на `fmt.Sprint` - строка получилась длинной, и потребовалось наращивать массив. 1 аллокация приходится на `reflect.ValueOf` - нужно выделить память под значение типа `reflect.Value`

Comment: В моем коде три лишних аллокации оказались связаны с escape алгоритмом. var lbuf = [256]byte может как выделиться на стеке функции, так и уйти в аллокацию. У меня видна зависимость от уровня вложения. Это раз. Ещё аллокация, возникает при втаскивании указателя на этот стековый буфер в структуру для сокращения длины параметров метода... структура тоже уходит в кучу.